# Flair Logo is a bit hard to see

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

On the Flair button the W favicon picture is hard and even not seen when used on the dark setting.

[image: Dark flair with dark-grey W]

I usally use the dark setting for my WP site which is at http://www.bens-wiki.co.cc/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's inevitable that certain colors of flair might not mesh well with the favicons at

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/apple-touch-icon.png

etc.

That's why we offer multiple flair colors, you may wish to pick a different one.

Comment: Perhaps an option would be to provide the flairs with transparency, then users could render their flairs inside an element(say a div) with the background colour of their choice. Sure text might appear in the wrong color, but maybe rather then having a skin option you could have a font color option instead to work alongside the transparency(the user gets full control that way). I'm just thinking out loud though.. :)